# How to update ui part rendered by template in knockoutjs

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I am dynamically creating a navigation list like this

```
self.NavList = ko.observableArray()

self.GenerateNavList = function () {
    self.NavList.push({ Description: 'APPROVAL', Link: '#approval-list-page', IsActive: false })
    self.NavList.push({ Description: 'TIME', Link: '#timesheet-list-page', IsActive: true })
    self.NavList.push({ Description: 'EXPENSE', Link: '#expense-list-page', IsActive: false })
    self.NavList.push({ Description: 'REQUISITION', Link: '#requisition-list-page', IsActive: false })
}
```

Now method to change it

```
self.SetActiveListItem = function (data) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.NavList(), function (item) {
        if (data.Description == item.Description) {
            item.IsActive = true
        } else {
            item.IsActive = false
        }
    })
    return true
}
```

And html template

```
<nav data-bind="template:{name: 'navlist', foreach: $root.NavList}" class="sixteen columns alpha omega"></nav>

<script type="text/html" id="navlist">
    <a data-transition="slide" href="#" data-bind="text:Description,attr:{href:Link},click:$root.SetActiveListItem,css:{active:IsActive}"></a>
</script>
```

Now the problem is that i am working on SPA with Jquery mobile and knockoutjs.
When i click on an item i want to set it active. But the item is not adding active class.

How can i make it active.

See the Fiddle 

## Here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I have found a solution for this. I need to make the `IsActive` property observable.

```
self.GenerateNavList = function () {
    self.NavList.push({ Description: 'APPROVAL', Link: '#approval-list-page', IsActive: ko.observable(false) })
    self.NavList.push({ Description: 'TIME', Link: '#timesheet-list-page', IsActive: ko.observable(true) })
    self.NavList.push({ Description: 'EXPENSE', Link: '#expense-list-page', IsActive: ko.observable(false) })
    self.NavList.push({ Description: 'REQUISITION', Link: '#requisition-list-page', IsActive: ko.observable(false) })
}
```

## Fiddle